# Ubuntu 20.04 Fractional scalling "cuting" elements

Tags: nvidia, xorg, gnome-shell, nvidia-prime

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 with a NVIDIA MX250. 
Firstly, nvidia-prime was not working. Even when selecting nvidia only, it was using Intel HD Graphics.

[image]

I've forced the use of NVIDIA as the primary GPU by creating /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-nvidia-drm-outputclass.conf with: Option "PrimaryGPU" "yes" (seen here https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NVIDIA_Optimus).
[image]

This works, now nvidia-settings show all options (before was showing only prime options, and nothing more - even when selecting NVIDIA Only).

But now, fractional scalling crops half of the screen. The funny thing is that when I try to printscreen, on the picture it looks fine, but in reality is not. I had to make a photo with my cellphone. As you can see, elements don't fit the screen (Note firefox title bar, for example).[image]

I really need fractional scalling, because everything is really small. KDE works fine, but I don't like it. And font scalling is not really good.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's actually a confirmed bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutter/+bug/1875285